# jquery, loading a page while page is not fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I have a JavaScript file with this line:

```
$('.item').load('page'); // (tried with document ready)
```

It does not work. It looks like the line executes before the page is fully loaded (because it works when I type the same line in the console).

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Nothing will be loaded unless the selector matches an element with the "item" class. Are you sure an element with the class item exists when the page loads initially and not added through code after? This sounds like a timing issue to me. Maybe add some console.write($('.item').length) code to see if it exists

Comment: I repeat, when i enter the same line fo code to console it works.
When i have tried to check with .length, it in console it shows ZERO :)

Comment: We can't tell you why it might be executing before the DOM loads because you haven't showed us how you're calling it or how you're constructing the DOM. Is `.item` created dynamically as a result of setTimeout that executes after 5 seconds? I don't know because I can't see the code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so if it's not working you need to post more code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of conditions you need to verify. The path to the document (including file extension) needs to be correct relative to the page that is using this load function. The element you are trying to load into needs to exist.

Are you getting errors in your console? What does it say?

This absolutely works.

```
<body>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.item').load('page.html');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: wel.. my project is a bit more complicated :))

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is not complicated at all - perhaps you can add more detail to the original question including error messages from your console or network log.

Comment: Clearly some of that complexity is the cause of the problem. Unfortunately, you haven't included any of that complexity here so we can't easily debug what we can't see...

Answer (score 0):

do

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
        $('.item').load('page');
     });
```

You need to call it when the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried waiting until the window is loaded?:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.item').load('page'); 
});
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle or live example we can see?